# Text Resize When Browser drag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed the site in bootstrap. when im trying to resize in browser the text are not re-sizing properly. I have tried few things in bootstrap nothing is working great in text level.

here my attempt to testing the site http://i.giphy.com/xT0BKp4niP44vGOjmM.gif

Answer (score 2):

Change your css with responsive width:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .mytext-xs {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .mytext-sm {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

And put on your class div :

```
<div class="mytext-sm mytext-xs">Lorem ipsum....</div> !
```